# play swf file with parts online

Tags: object, flash

i have some old flash games.
They contains:

- a .swf file
- a folder with files with type 'File'

when i use following code it runs locally but when i upload it on my server online then it doesn't work.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="race.swf" id="histo2" style="width:100%; height:100%;float: none; vertical-align:middle">
            <param name="movie" value="race.swf" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><!-- sameDomain -->
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="menu" value="false" />
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>Click below button to enable flash player or to install it.</h3>
                        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </object>
```

Comment: You should contact the developer, the games were URL-locked, probably.

Comment: **(1)** Use full server URL `https://www.... etc` for SWF path. **(2)** Use `embed` tag (not `object` tag).